# {solved} - How to show Thumbnail Previews over Taskbar icons in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, thumbnails

My Thumbnail Previews over Taskbar icons in Windows 7 is missing. After some research I have found that I have to go to Computer >> Properties >> Advanced system settings >> and check "Enable Desktop Composition". Yet I have not found this option in my Windows 7 64-bit.

Why is that and what should I do?

Edit: [image]

Edit 2 solved: I have made a regular system update to Windows 7 and the option has appeared with "Enable Desktop Composition". Still Windows 7 is not yet SP1. So I can say the problem has been solved.Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Computer >> Properties >> Advanced system settings >>Performance - settings

[image]

Comment: Thank you for comment, It seems I do not have these options. I edited the question uploaded a pic of the options I have.

Comment: fqwe@ unfortunately did not work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: did u try troubleshoot as shown [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/976170/guided-help-troubleshoot-aero-problems-in-windows-7)

Comment: Where can I begin a troubleshoot?

Comment: Yes, thank you, it shows a problem found: Video card driver does not support Aero effects. I do not know if updating windows or the driver might fix the problem.

Comment: Yes may be  or u can try these steps if u want go further 
[link](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005696/graphics-drivers.html#checkcolor)

Comment: Ok, i will thank you fqwe. appreciate your help.

Comment: fqwe@ I have made a regular system update to Windows 7 and the option has appeared with "Enable Desktop Composition". So I can say the problem has been solved. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Make a regular system update to Windows 7 and the option  "Enable Desktop Composition" will appear.

Specifically speaking, After updating to these options in the photo below, I have restored my My Thumbnail Previews over Taskbar icons in Windows 7

[image]

Note: I had to update many times before reaching to these update options.